# Resize image in code

Tags: objective-c, image

I have looked at some of the similar questions here on stackoverflow, but I am unable to make any of the examples work.

I have an image on my storyboard, imgBubble, which i am trying to move and resize using code. I have linked the imgBubble correctly. I am able to access it here, I tested with setting it hidden attribute, which worked. I am sure I am doing something wrong, but I cannot understand what. The imgBubble is situated directly within this controller view.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 100  , 500, 20);
    self.imgBubble.frame = frame;
}
```

Comment: This does seem right to me but have you tried `[[self imgBubble] setFrame:frame];`???

Comment: No, but I tried it now. Doesn't work for me either. Don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: What is the position before you try and update??? Add `NSLog(@"Before update : %@", [[self imgBubble] frame]);` before you update the frame and add `NSLog(@"After update : %@", [[self imgBubble] frame]);` after updating the frame and tell us what the output is.

Comment: had the change the NSLOGs provided a bit, to `NSLog(@"Before update: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.imgBubble.frame));
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 100  , 500, 20);
    self.imgBubble.frame = frame;
    NSLog(@"After update : %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.imgBubble.frame));`
it outputs: 2014-04-10 08:32:34.324 Jones[699:60b] Before update: {{122, 455}, {676, 263}}
2014-04-10 08:32:34.325 Jones[699:60b] After update : {{0, 100}, {500, 20}}

So, it is changed, but not visually.